# PySide: как сменить значение всех QLabel?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt4

На форме находятся 3 Label, которые нужно сменить, если оставить один Label, то он замечательно меняется в функции. Я решил ввести переменную в виде невидимого Label, присвоить значение ему и уже его значение менять, невидимый QLabel значение меняет, но остальные его не принимают.

```
.....
class PingTab(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

    self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(a)
    self.lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel(b)
    self.lbl3 = QtGui.QLabel(c)
    self.ping = QtGui.QPushButton('Ping')
    self.out1 = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.out2 = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.out3 = QtGui.QLabel()

    self.out = QtGui.QLabel()
    out_s = self.out.setText(u'Проверяю...')
    self.out1.setText(self.out.text())
    self.out2.setText(self.out.text())
    self.out3.setText(self.out.text())

    gr = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
    gr.addWidget(self.lbl, 0,0)
    gr.addWidget(self.ping, 0,2)
    gr.addWidget(self.lbl2, 1,0)
    gr.addWidget(self.lbl3, 2,0)
    gr.addWidget(self.out1, 0,1)
    gr.addWidget(self.out2, 1,1)
    gr.addWidget(self.out3, 2,1)

    self.ping.connect(self.ping, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.check_ping)
```

Тело функции:

```
....

def check_ping(self):

    for i in ('a','b','c'):
        host = globals()[i]         
        ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", host],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                        )

        out,error = ping.communicate()

        if ping.returncode !=0:
           out_s = u'Ошибка'
           self.out.setText(out_s)    
        else:
           out_s = u'Ok'
           self.out.setText(out_s)    
    ....
```

QLabel'ы не меняют своих значений после проверки.Где я ошибся?
Еще был вариант записать в ветвление if..else все Label, то есть:

```
  if ping.returncode !=0:
    self.out1.setText(u'Ошибка')
    self.out2.setText(u'Ошибка')
    self.out3.setText(u'Ошибка')
  else:
    self.out1.setText(u'Ok')
    self.out2.setText(u'Ok')
    self.out3.setText(u'Ok')
```

Но в этом случае все Label принимают значение 'Ok'. Хотя есть хосты, которые возвращают ошибку.

#### Правильный блок

```
def check_ping(self):

    s =0
    for i in ('a','b','c'):
        host = globals()[i]

        s = s+1 
        ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", host],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                        )

        out,error = ping.communicate()

        if ping.returncode !=0:
            getattr(self,'out{0}'.format(s)).setText(u'Ошибка')

        else:
            getattr(self,'out{0}'.format(s)).setText(u'Оk')
```

Comment: А что должно происходить после проверки ping.returncode?

Comment: а из кода не понятно??? Меняются надписи QLabel.

Comment: Не понимаю строчку ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", host], Зачем при смене надписей надо делать пинг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-нибудь типа `getattr(self, 'out{0}'.format(i)).setText(u'Обшибка')`, где i -- номер метки (1-out1, 2-out2, 3-out3)

Исправлено. После self ошибочно была точка.

Комментарии мне уже недоступны, спрошу здесь: что такое `self.out(s).setPixmap(icon)`. out здесь -- вызов функции с параметром s?

Comment: invalid Syntax возникает на .'out{0}'. Если переделать на .out(0). тогда вылетает что нет атрибута out у класса PingTab.
Или я что-то не понял))

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатка. После self должна стоять запятая. `getattr(self, 'out{0}'.format(i)).setText("Ok")`

Comment: Я забыл, что i определено в цикле. Значение должно быть от 1 до 3. Т.е. какая-нибудь переменная-счётчик.

Comment: Зачем? Цикл должен быть один, иначе номер метки и адрес будут рассогласованы. `#
j = 0
for i in l.values:
    j = j + 1
    ... 
    'out{0}'.format(j)
#` ну или ещё масса вариантов

Comment: с изображениями тоже самое getattr(....).setPixmap(icon) или есть какая-то другая конструкция?

Comment: `print getattr.__doc__`

    getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value
    
    Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
    When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.

Comment: Дело в том что аргумент существует, self.out(s).setPixmap(icon), но цикл меняет изображение только у одного Label.